# How do I know when the sound to microphone is begin?

Tags: c#, .net, microphone, naudio

I have one problem. How do create program, that throw exception, while begin sound in microphone. Microphone always on, that is noise is always too. Roughly, if I speak to microphone, program throw exceprion. I'm using NAudio. Please help

Comment: do you really want an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the WaveInStream class in NAudio. It allows you to open microphone and receive events containing the latest captured bytes. Processing captured bytes allows to understand if sound began or did not began.

Comment: Ok, I use WaveInStream, I have buffer array. If I say to microphone, amplitude increases. You are offering watch this? If yes, I dont know that how many times amplitude increases.

Comment: for (int n = 0; n < e.BytesRecorded; n += 2)
{
    short value = BitConverter.ToInt16(e.Buffer, n);        
}
then check Math.Abs(value)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [VoiceRecorder project](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/) that uses `NAudio`. Here's an example of detecting voice level. And when chosen voice level is raised, you can throw an exception.